# How to get POST body without using body parser

Tags: javascript, express, stream, body-parser

```
module.exports=function(app){
//app is passed in from app.js
//app is a express application


var data=[
   {item:"cheese"},{item:"milk"},{item:"strawberrys"}
 ]
app.get('/todo',function(req, res){
   res.render('todo',{data:data});
});
app.post('/todo',function(req, res){
var data="";
req.on('data', function(chunk){
   data+=chunk;
 });
req.on('end', function(){
    console.log(data);
  })
 });
 }
```

A couple questions regarding the code above, is 'data' an event that you can set a stream on and the chunk function returns the stream in chunks? Also when I printed out the data from the 'end' event it gave me item=eggs when it was an object I passed through that was {item:"eggs"}. Why did it not give me the object? Also in the 'data' event it returns it in a buffer of bytes but in the 'end' event it returns as an object?

Comment: can you share the code you are using to POST the data to the server?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the `post` content type

If you're posting using: `content-type: application/json` it will show the JSON data.
Example:

```
POST /todo HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json

{"key":"value"}
```

If you're posting using: `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` it will show `key1=value1&key2=value2` etc.
If you're not using `application/json` the request will be like this.

Example:

```
POST /todo HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

key=value
```